# How can I get a variable from terminal to use it in my script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm writing small programs that are allowing me to do common commands with just two or three words max like `sudo apt-get update` I made it upt something like that

Now I'm trying to write a script which will allow me to install programs from terminal
the command is `sudo apt-get install 'program'`

I'm asking here how can I save the command 'program' in a variable to use it in my script so I can write in terminal inst 'program' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you invoke a script like

```
myscript parameter1 parameter2
```

the parameter1, parameter2 etc. values from the command line are available inside the script as *positional parameters* `$0`, `$1`, ... etc

- parameter $0 contains the name by which the script was invoked (*myscript*)
- parameter $1 contains the value *parameter1*
- parameter $2 contains the value *parameter2*
- and so on

So in your case if you want to run your script like

```
inst program
```

to install *program*, then inside the script you can write

```
apt-get install "$1"
```

See for example [Handling positional parameters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams) at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org