# Write bash script to perform series of commands with file

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I would like to write a bash script to do the following commands:

```
convert -density 300 file_in file_out
convert file_out -trim file_out
```

I would like to execute the command with `conv file_in file_out`, where `file_in` is an existing file that I need to specify, and `file_out` is the output name of the new file that I also need to specify.

I'd appreciate some help with this, thanks!

EDIT: My question is essentially how to use a variable specified in the terminal in a bash script, which might be a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398357/how-can-i-get-a-variable-from-terminal-to-use-it-in-my-script).

Comment: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_writing_shell_scripts.php . for i in __ do convert $i $i.out done

Comment: I *think* what you're asking is [How can I get a variable from terminal to use it in my script?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/398357/how-can-i-get-a-variable-from-terminal-to-use-it-in-my-script)

Comment: @Zanna, steeldriver is right, that is what I meant. Thank you

Comment: Do you need a script for this? I believe `convert -density 300 -trim file_in file_out` would do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_IN=$1
FILE_OUT=$2

convert -density 300 "$FILE_IN" "$FILE_OUT"
convert "$FILE_OUT" -trim "$FILE_OUT"

exit $?
```

If you save that file as `conv` and `chmod +x conv` you should be able to execute it as desired:

```
conv file_in file_out
```