# Input from console

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am very new to bash, so please excuse this (highly probable) noob question.

I am writing a script that outputs a "pyramide" with height x. I have managed to get the code right, but x is supposed to come from the command used to start the script. So if the user types pyramide 5 in the console this starts the scripts and gives it 5 lines. I am used to using read input, but this one is new to me.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: You can use the script's *positional parameters* - see for example [How can I get a variable from terminal to use it in my script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398357/how-can-i-get-a-variable-from-terminal-to-use-it-in-my-script/)

Comment: $1 did it, thank you very much steeldriver! Cool feature!

Answer (score 1):

Best I could come up with:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -i a=$1
eval "printf -vb xx%.s {0..$a}"
while ((a>c++)); do
    printf '\033[%dC%s\n' $((a-c+1)) ${b::((2*c-1))}
done
```

Comment: Please don't ever use `eval` with user input! It is hackers christmas and easter in one day -> `run.sh "1; evil_command;"`. You could use `seq 0 "$a"` instead of `eval "{0..$a}"`

Comment: @pLumo bash only, can use a while ... b+= will almost yield same benchmark.

Comment: think `declare -i` will keep evil doers away...